# How to create Listview dynamically when clicking card items in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have a list of categories displayed in listview. Now I am trying to create the subcategories when clicking each of the category list and display it into another listview in flutter.

For each categories , I have to create another list of subcategories dynamically. I have json data and good working category list. I have to create sub categories based on category list.

I have a model class that contains category details and subcategory details as well.

How could i achieve this?

Model Class

```
  class ProductCategoryModel {
   String categoryName;
   String categoryImage;
   String categoryId;
   List<SubCategory> subcategory;

    ProductCategoryModel(
     {this.categoryName,
     this.categoryImage,
     this.categoryId,
     this.subcategory});

    factory ProductCategoryModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['children'] as List;
    print(list.runtimeType);
    List<SubCategory> subCategoryList =
    list.map((i) => SubCategory.fromJson(i)).toList();

   return ProductCategoryModel(
   categoryName: json['name'],
   categoryImage: json['image'],
   categoryId: json['category_id'],
   subcategory: subCategoryList,
   );
  }
 }

  class SubCategory {
  String subCategoryId;
  String subCategoryName;

  SubCategory({this.subCategoryId, this.subCategoryName});

  factory SubCategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> subJson) {
     return SubCategory(
     subCategoryId: subJson['SubCategoryModel'],
      subCategoryName: subJson['name'],
     );
   }
 }
```

Json Response :

```
   {
    "category_id": "1",
     "name": "Vehicle",
     "column": "1",
        "children": [
           {
             "category_id": "101",
             "name": "Two Wheeler",
             "product_count": " (0)"
           },
           {
             "category_id": "102",
             "name": "Four Wheeler",
             "product_count": " (1)"
           }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: It will be better if you can share your expected UI screen,

Comment: Horizontal list view for Categories.. And when clicking the category item create another listview dynamically under the category list horizontally.

Comment: Okay so just add two listviews on your screen 1 at the top of the screen and 2nd is just below the first and onTap of the category, Change the state and set the subcategory of the selected category.

Comment: Yes, I have to add data dynamically to the sub category listview. I have json data as shown in above code, And how can i map these data

Comment: I have added Json response here, And the model class..

Answer (score 0):

I have created this demo.

Check it, then ask me anything if you need.

Trick is here, creating new boolean list based on your categories, then rendering subCategories based on that boolean list conditionally.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool success = false;

  static List<String> categories = ['1', '2', '3'];
  static List<List<String>> subCategories = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i']
  ];
  static List<bool> activeCategories = List.filled(categories.length, false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: Center(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        activeCategories[index] =
                            activeCategories.elementAt(index) == true
                                ? false
                                : true;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      categories.elementAt(index),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              activeCategories.elementAt(index)
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: subCategories.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, subIndex) {
                        return SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(subCategories
                                .elementAt(index)
                                .elementAt(subIndex)),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  : SizedBox(),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```